# Coin change dinamic programming: having issues with it

Tags: c++

So i am asked to write a recursive program to count all possible ways to get N with US cents (100, 50, 25, 10, 5, 1)
I am having issues with it. But can't understand where is my mistake. please help me.

```
    #include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int i,coins[8];
    long long a;
    long long solve(long long a){
        if(a==0){
            return 1;
        }
        if(a<0){
            return 0;
        }
        long long k=0;
        for(i=1; i<=6; i++){
            k+=solve(a-coins[i]);
        }
        return k;
    }
    int main(){
        coins[1]=1; 
        coins[2]=5;
        coins[3]=10; 
        coins[4]=25;
        coins[5]=50; 
        coins[6]=100;
        cin>>a;
        cout<<solve(a)<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) it?

Comment: Arrays starts with index 0, not 1. Proper way `int coins[] = { 1, 5, 10 ... };`

Comment: i know. but i can use it from 1 . thats ok. look. i used for(i=1; i<=6; i++)
from 1 to 6

Comment: Of course you can then do not ask others to look into your code, deal with it by yourself.

Comment: *"I am having issues with it"* What's the nature of those issues? What outcome do you expect, what do you observe, and how do the two differ?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik nature of the issue  - "I can use it that way it is ok", yea use global variable for counter in recursive function, seems not ok enough.

Comment: there are some obvious issues with your code (`a` vs `a`, indices starting at 1 when they should start at `0` plus some minor ones), but most likely they arent related to the problem you have in mind. To be sure you need to tell us what **you** think is the issue

Comment: i changed coins[] so now it starts with 0; a is not global. and i used for(coin : coins), now there is another issue. but i think that i can figure it out(i guess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But can't understand where is my mistake.

You should not use global variables unless it is really necessary, especially in recursive functions.

Note: using arrays not the way it is designed yet another way to produce errors in your program. Create your array properly initialized:

```
int coins[] = { 1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100 };
```

and you can iterate it simpler way:

```
 for( int coin : coins )
```

and irony is it would fix your problem as well.

Comment: that helped. but i have another mistake. look. for example i say solve(6)=solve(5)+solve(1); but its not like that. i use noth 1+5 and 5+1; so that abother problem. but thanks. you were right

Comment: To fix that you can pass index to start with to your function (and call it with 0 from main)